# Visitor pattern - interface vs abstract class

Tags: c#, interface, abstract-class, visitor-pattern

I'm currently trying to write a simple compiler for even simpler language, but I have problem with adding the `Visitor` pattern. 
I have a `ILanguageVisitor` interface that looks like this:

```
interface ILanguageVisitor {
        void Visit(GlobalStructure cs);
        void Visit(GotoStructure cs);
        void Visit(IfStructure cs);
        void Visit(ElseIfStructure cs);
        void Visit(ElseStructure cs);
        ...
}
```

All of these methods must be implement to create concrete visitor for specific architecture. But above this, there are some methods and fields that should be common for all possible visitors.

That is for example functionality of blocks, which consist of two or more `Visit` calls, like:

```
Visit(If) 
    ...
Visit(Else) 
    ... 
Visit(EndIf) 

Visit(For) 
    ... 
Visit(EndFor)
```

This is because of the rules of block start and termination (like there can't be two `else`s in one block, or that child block can't be terminated by parent as in case `For ... If ... EndFor`).

My question is: if I have a behavior that should be common for all `Visitor`s, should I create an abstract Visitor class, which would make these specific methods `virtual` and other `abstract`?

Will be there any loss of `Visitor`´s point if I add a default behavior to its base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these kind of cases, I believe the best solution is to have both an interface and a base class which implements this interface and allows users to override certain methods. This way, the user can decide whether he'd like to:

- Inherit the base class and have some or most functionality already implemented for him (with the possible cost of flexibility)
- Implement the entire interface himself, allowing for maximum control and flexibility.

Comment: Using both seems good, I just thought it would be unclear. But when somebody else uses it, I can either :) Thanks.

Comment: (Except for DTO's, I can't think of a case where I don't just automatically create interfaces - go ReSharper!)

Answer (score 2):

As for me the visitor pattern is a smart If-Else construction, take a look on this solution

```
public static class Visitor
{
    public static IFuncVisitor<TBase, TResult> For<TBase, TResult>()
        where TBase : class
    {
        return new FuncVisitor<TBase, TResult>();
    }

    public static IActionVisitor<TBase> For<TBase>()
        where TBase : class
    {
        return new ActionVisitor<TBase>();
    }

    private sealed class ActionVisitor<TBase> : IActionVisitor<TBase>
        where TBase : class
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<TBase>> _repository =
            new Dictionary<Type, Action<TBase>>();

        public void Register<T>(Action<T> action)
            where T : TBase
        {
            _repository[typeof(T)] = x => action((T)x);
        }


        public void Visit<T>(T value)
            where T : TBase
        {
            Action<TBase> action = _repository[value.GetType()];
            action(value);
        }
    }

    private sealed class FuncVisitor<TBase, TResult> : IFuncVisitor<TBase, TResult>
        where TBase : class
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<TBase, TResult>> _repository =
            new Dictionary<Type, Func<TBase, TResult>>();

        public void Register<T>(Func<T, TResult> action)
            where T : TBase
        {
            _repository[typeof(T)] = x => action((T)x);
        }

        public TResult Visit<T>(T value)
            where T : TBase
        {
            Func<TBase, TResult> action = _repository[value.GetType()];
            return action(value);
        }
    }
}

public interface IFuncVisitor<in TBase, TResult>
    where TBase : class
{
    void Register<T>(Func<T, TResult> action)
        where T : TBase;

    TResult Visit<T>(T value)
        where T : TBase;
}

public interface IActionVisitor<in TBase>
    where TBase : class
{
    void Register<T>(Action<T> action)
        where T : TBase;

    void Visit<T>(T value)
        where T : TBase;
}
```

Usage example:

```
IActionVisitor<Letter> visitor = Visitor.For<Letter>();
visitor.Register<A>(x => Console.WriteLine(x.GetType().Name));
visitor.Register<B>(x => Console.WriteLine(x.GetType().Name));

Letter a = new A();
Letter b = new B();
visitor.Visit(a);
visitor.Visit(b);
```

Where `Letter` is the base class for `A` and `B`

Comment: Stolen from: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/563043/Dynamic-Visitor-Pattern nah?

Comment: No, it's my article, you can take a look the same articles in the stackoverflow profile :)

Comment: LOL, sorry (feeling ashamed). But still, despite the length of copy/paste, it didn't help.

Comment: It's ok :) About Interface vs class, try to think about purpose, as i see your goal is to find concrete class type `GlobalStructure`, `IfStructure` etc. All Interface and class are pollute your business logic, that's why I think you can take a look on Dynamic Visitor

Answer (score 1):

Design patterns are solutions for *design* problems, not *implementation rules*. So if you choose to implement a visitor pattern using interfaces, abstract classes, or both (like @AdiLester suggested) is completly up to you

If I remember correctly, the original GOF book used a lot of C++ exmples, where there is not even a language element interface.